# Connect R to a remote SAS database

Tags: r, database, sas

I neeed to stablish a connection between R and SAS remote database.

I have the credential, machine name, port number, user and password, but I don't know how to connect R to that database with these credentials.

Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: Is SAS a type of database? What kind of connection protocols can you use with it? What operating system are you using?

Comment: @cory SAS is Statistical Analysis Software, an application that does statistical analysis, similar to R, from the 1970's. www.sas.com

Comment: You need an ODBC connection. Do you know what type of database it is, ie Oracle, MS SQL? Do you know if the data sets are server based or SAS based (SAS uses either). Try RODBC with your info to connect.

Comment: I'm familiar with the SAS software, but not the SAS database.

Comment: The data sets are SAS based files. And the SAS application is remote, I have the credentials for that remote machina then I would like to have access to the datasets @Reeza

Comment: R has a couple of packages for reading SAS datasets.  There is no need to "connect" to read a file.

Comment: You'll need to connect to the server using ODBC, then you can try and read the files from there. I don't know if that's actually possible but feel like it should be given the recent integrations between the systems. https://db.rstudio.com/odbc/

Comment: @Tom wouldn't you have to connect to the server in some manner to get the file?

Comment: Files are files. Moving them around has little to do with SAS or R.

Comment: There are two steps to this: 1. Connect to the local server, such as mounting a remote location. 2. Read the .sas7bdat file, which can be done in R with `read_sas`. Once you mount remotely or gain some sort of connection that gives you access to the server's directory where the .sas7bdat is stored, you can read the file as if it were local. .sas7bdat files are simply files that hold data. You can copy and move them around like any other file.